# Proving lemma in Isabelle

Tags: proof, isabelle

I have a function

```
 fun exec :: "com ⇒ state ⇒ nat ⇒ state option" where
   "exec _ s 0 = None" 
 | "exec SKIP s (Suc f) = Some s" 
 | "exec (x::=v) s (Suc f) = Some (s(x:=aval v s))" 
 | "exec (c1;;c2) s (Suc f) = (
     case (exec c1 s f) of None ⇒ None | Some s' ⇒ exec c2 s' f)" 
 | "exec (IF b THEN c1 ELSE c2) s (Suc f) = 
     (if bval b s then exec c1 s f else exec c2 s f)" 
 | "exec (WHILE b DO c) s (Suc f) = (
     if bval b s then 
       (case (exec c s f) of 
         None ⇒ None | 
          Some s' ⇒ exec (WHILE b DO c) s' f) 
     else Some s)"
```

and I need to prove

```
lemma exec_imp_bigstep: "exec c s f = Some s' ⟹ (c,s) ⇒ s'"
```

holds. How can I do that? I tried induction, `auto`, `blast`, `sledgehammer`. But it seems a different approach is needed.

---

The Lemma says that there exist values for c and s, so that there exists a s' that is the result of function f with values c and s. I wonder why you need c and s in the Definition, and why you can not just write

lemma exec_imp_bigstep: "exec c f = Some s' ⟹ c ⇒ s'"

As to the proof, my idea would be to show that

lemma exec_imp_bigstep: "exec c s f = Some s' ⟹ (c,s) ⇒ s'" holds if

lemma exec_imp_bigstep: "exec c f = Some s' ⟹ c ⇒ s'"
and
lemma exec_imp_bigstep: "exec s f = Some s' ⟹ s ⇒ s'" .

Comment: Just blindly shooting at a lemma with proof methods is (most of the time) not very helpful. Do *you* think the lemma is correct? If yes, *why*? This should give you a hint how to go at a proof. Moreover, it might be helpful for answering your question if you would at least mention where the definition of your big-step semantics comes from.

Comment: Answering a question why `exec` takes a state: `exec` computes a new state from a given one. In particular the state is directly changed by an assignment. And every non-trivial command can change it as well. It might be possible to use an empty state as an initial one, but then a helper function would be required to deal with a command other than the first one.